# CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to

Tags: c#

Tengo estas lineas de codigo donde array le estoy asignando los valores de una lista y posteriormente mandarlo a su metodo ubicado en webservice, anterirormente tenia la linea de esta manera:

```
var r = cliente.Save(array);
```

Y estaba todo perfecto al poco tiempo, me marco error por lo que decidi cambiarlo a esta otra forma:

```
var r = cliente.Save(array.ToArray());
```

Cuando actualice la referencia, ahora me marca este error:

> CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to

Este es el codigo completo:

```
var array = new List<string>();
foreach (var x in lista)
{
    array.Add(x);
}
var r = cliente.Save(array.ToArray());
```

Que esta causando que de alguna forma se corrompa, o de que manera puedo arreglar este defecto?

Comment: Según el error a qué tipo de dato no puede convertir? No se indica cuando causa el error?

Comment: Tu metodo save recibe un array?  y para no convertir porque no usas directamente un string[] ?

Comment: La información que brindas es incompleta, no incluyes el código del método `cliente.Save` y la información del error esta truncada, `CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to` (aquí a continuación el compilador te indica a que tipo de dato es que no puede convertirse, pero no lo incluiste), faltaría saber que argumento espera recibir tu `cliente.Save`, si quieres que se te ayude debes incluir el código del método `cliente.Save` o la sentencia del error completa,sin truncarla. Cualquier recomendación que te den seria especulando sobre como convertir.